# CSS transform scale animation not working in Firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox

I've got the following animation working in Chrome, but not in Firefox. I dont know whether i've missed something, any help is much appreciated. Result should scale (grow and shrink) text Please see:

`<span class="t1">A</span>`https://jsfiddle.net/zf1hy5be/

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not work in Chrome also, I use Chrome. But I see a big problem, **CSS transfroms** does not works on **inline level elements**(I mean only display: inline and span is by default inline level), they are just ignored, so change that to any other value you need.